# LNK1104 error while installing Mendel Development Tool

Tags: pip, google-coral

I am having trouble getting my system set up to use my new Tinker Edge T.

I have successfully installed Python on my Windows 10 laptop.

Now trying to run the Mendel install in the command prompt: `python -m pip install --user mendel-development-tool`

The process gets a fair way through but fails in the cffi step with this error:

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'uuid.lib'
```

I have used Visual Studio Installer to make sure I have the latest C++ SDK, etc.

In order to get as far as I did in the install, I had to add the following to the 'INCLUDE' environment variable as it initially was unable to find the `io.h` and a couple of other header files.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um

In a similar way, I have tried adding the following to the PATH environment variable, but it didn't solve the issue:

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\um\x64

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling all windows SDKs and Python (V3.10.0) and instead installing Python V3.9.7. I haven't reinstalled the windows SDKs, so possible there was a conflict there.